# MODX endless saving SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: extjs, extjs3, modx

I have to deal with MODX Revolution, when I edit any page and press Save, the progress bar keeps loading forever, console says SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' ext-all.js:21

Tried to disable all extensions in package manager

Tested on Chrome 59 and Firefox 54

MODX Revolution 2.5.2-pl

Ext JS 3.4

IIS 8

Comment: You should inspect your page with FireBug or similar. You'll probably find that is being generated incorrectly.

Comment: "Syntax error at '<'" usually means that the response returned from the server is HTML (e.g. an error page), not JSON (the expected answer).

Comment: I had this problem and It was my Chrome Extension **JSON Viewer Awesome** causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this. In Chrome console I used beautifier to beautify ext-all.js. Then I replaced compressed javascript with beautified one. After a bit of debugging I've found this piece of code:

```
try {
    A = r.contentWindow.document || r.contentDocument || g.frames[l].document;
    if (A) {
        if (A.body) {
            if (/textarea/i.test((z = A.body.firstChild || {}).tagName)) {
                w.responseText = z.value
            } else {
                w.responseText = A.body.innerHTML
            }
        }
        w.responseXML = A.XMLDocument || A
    }
}
```

The problem was that A.body.innerHTML returned JSON wrapped with "pre" tag. I didn't want to dig further into this, so just added

```
w.responseText = w.responseText.match(/\{.*\}/)[0]
```

This should be fixed by extjs or modix team I guess...

Comment: This is not a proper fix. The problem is that an AJAX request (which the manager uses a lot) returned HTML, instead of JSON. It typically does that when there's an uncaught PHP error of sorts. Inspecting the outgoing AJAX requests and their responses is how you would find out the actual problem, so you can apply a targeted fix for that.